# React: Table search query doesn't filter the table data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a table with data that I'm getting from props. Here is the structure of the data:

`[{user1: value, data1: value}, {user2: value, data2: value}]`

What I'm trying to do, is to write a 'Search field' and a 'Column selector' that will filter the table inputs by the input query (this query will be checked only in the chosen column scope).

This is how the code looks like now:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    query: '',
    columnToQuery: 'user'
  }


  componentDidMount = () => {
    const { loadTestData } = this.props;
    loadTestData();
  }

  getTableRows = () => {
    // testData format is:
    // [{user1: value, data1: value}, {user2: value, data2: value}]
    const { testData } = this.props;

    const testDataFiltered = this.state.query 
      ? testData.filter(elem => elem[this.state.columnToQuery].includes(this.state.query))
      : testData

    return testDataFiltered.map(item => ({
      // Id - uuid timestamp 
      id: `${uuidv1()}`,
      row: [
        moment(item.date).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss'),
        item.user,
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { testData } = this.props;

    console.log(this.state);

    if (!testData) {
      return (
        <div className="loader-view mt-25 w-100">
          <CircularProgress />
        </div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="app-wrapper">
        <div id="my-tasks-page" className="row animated slideInUpTiny animation-duration-3">
          <CardBox
            styleName="col-12"
            cardStyle="p-0"
            heading={<IntlMessages id="pages.testData" />}
            headerOutside
          >
            <Paper>

              <TextField
                id="dataSearch"
                label="Search field"
                type="search"
                margin="normal"
                value={this.state.query}
                onChange={(event) => 
                  this.setState({ query: event.target.value })
                }
                fullWidth
              />

              <FormControl className="w-100 mb-2">
                <InputLabel htmlFor="">Select a column</InputLabel>
                <Select
                  value={this.state.columnToQuery}
                  onChange={(event) => 
                    this.setState({ columnToQuery: event.target.value })
                  }
                >
                  <MenuItem value='date'>Date</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value='user'>Executant</MenuItem>
                </Select>
              </FormControl>

              <DataTable
                columns={columns}
                data={this.getTableRows()}
                query={this.state.query}
                columnToQuery={this.state.columnToQuery}
                noDataMessage="Currently there are no info" 
              />

            </Paper>
          </CardBox>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**I consoled log the state and `testData` array, `filter` function in `getTableRows()` is working properly, but table is not rerendering with a filtered data, what may be a reason?**

Comment: did you try like this : `componentDidMount = () => {
    const { loadTestData } = this.props;
    loadTestData();
   getTableRows();
  }`

Comment: it throws an error 'getTableRows' is not defined

Comment: try binding: `this.getTableRows = this.getTableRow.bind(this);`  inside this constructor 

or just call `this.getTableRows()` inside `componentDidMount()`

Comment: I found a reason: in DataTable component I assign props to the state and filling the table from the state. After props change it just doesn't update the state of DataTable component

Comment: alright :) that makes sense. You should make them separate.

Comment: Yes. you need to save in state data and query, and on change input||select update state of data ( this.getTableRows()  ) and query. try and get feedback :)